# The code is error free but name is labelled in red

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart

I am trying to make a simple android application with flutter and dart.While coding for the registration page I didnt find error in the file but file name reflects in red.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsdwQ.png)]

I tried changing the file name to camel case then to snake case but nothing worked.

Comment: That is because the git is enabled in the project but you have not added that file to git. Try right click on file in project tab and then go to Git -> + Add. This will add your file to git and then you will be able to see it turned green as it is a new file that you have added.

Answer (score 0):

red filename means that you haven't added this file to repository... right click on tab with this name and pick Git -> Add

white one (like `screen.dart`) means that file is in repo and is current, not modified

blue one (e.g. `main.dart`) means that file is in repo, but is modified locally, so you have some code changes pending to commit

Answer (score 0):

That is because the git is enabled in the project but you have not added that file to git. Try this :

right click on file in project tab and then go to Git -> + Add.

This will add your file to git and then you will be able to see it turned green as it is a new file that you have added.